# Fire frequency calculation in GEE with FireCCI data

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, count

I have a problem with calculating the fire frequency (burned area count) in GEE. I want to calculate the counts of the fire in my study area from 2001-2020(the data availability of the FireCCI data). The data provides ''burn date'' which is a value between 1-366, indicating the burning date of the certain year.

What I want is to sum the layer with fire occurrences up to visualize the fire frequency within 20 years(the fire counts). Here I have used two approaches but the result seems incorrect because the highest value is 18, which is supposed to be a lot higher since it's a 20 year dataset, but the fire pattern seems fine. I wonder which part of the script went wrong.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ESA/CCI/FireCCI/5_1')
                .filterDate('2001-01-01', '2020-12-01')
                .filterBounds(ROI)
                .map(function(image){return image.clip(ROI)});
print(dataset)


// make a function to mask images based on the ConfidenceLevel band                  
var filterConfidence = function(image){
  var mask = image.select('ConfidenceLevel').gt(70);
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};

// map over the image collection and apply the mask
var confidentDataset = dataset.map(filterConfidence);
var burnedArea_Confidence_70 = confidentDataset.select('BurnDate');


//Method1_calculate the count of the burned area
var firedaysFunction = function(image){
  return image.gte(1);
};
var firedays = burnedArea_Confidence_70.map(firedaysFunction);
//The total number of days with fires over the past 20 years(fire count calculation)
var firedaysCount = firedays.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

//map the fire frequency
var burncount_color ={
  palette: [
    '0000FF', '00FFFF', '00FF00', 'FFFF00', 'FF0000'
  ]
};
Map.addLayer(firedaysCount, burncount_color, 'firedaysCount');


//Method2_calculate the count of the burned area-
// Reduce the collection to an image with burn date counts
var burnCount = burnedArea_Confidence_70.count();

// map the fire frequency
var burncount_color ={
  palette: [
    '0000FF', '00FFFF', '00FF00', 'FFFF00', 'FF0000'
  ]
};
Map.addLayer(burnCount, burncount_color, 'Burn Count Image');
```

Comment: Each image in the [FireCCI dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ESA_CCI_FireCCI_5_1#description) represents one *month* of data, so both of your current methods are calculating the total number of months with detected fire, rather than the number of days.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, if it represents one month of data, then I wonder why the value of FireCCI is from 1 to 366?

Comment: They use the pixel value to encode the day that burning was first detected, but the temporal resolution for the dataset is monthly. So for example if a pixel burned on January 1 and January 30, the January image will only show a pixel value of 1.

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron, does it mean it is impossible to create a fire frequency map for 20 years based on how many "days" it is burned?

Comment: It won't be possible with the FireCCI dataset, but you could try the [FIRMS dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/FIRMS), which maps daily hotspots.

Comment: ok! Thank you! :)